# jquery this returning weird response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to toggle an "add to cart" button

```
function addOrRemoveFromCart(){
    alert($(this).val)
    if ($(this).hasClass("add_to_cart")){
        alert('yes');
        $(this).prop('value', 'Remove from Cart');
        $(this).removeClass("add_to_cart");
        $(this).addClass("remove_from_cart");
    }
    else{
        alert('no');
        $(this).prop('value', 'Add to Cart');
        $(this).addClass("add_to_cart");
        $(this).removeClass("remove_from_cart");
    }
}
```

and this is my button

```
<input id="069874" class="add_to_cart button" type="button" onclick="addOrRemoveFromCart()" value="Add To Cart">
```

`$(this).hasClass("add_to_cart")` was returning false

`$(this).val` returns a very long output that has nothing to do with the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`.val` is a function**

Call `$(this).val()` to get the value

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup this function as a binding for 'add to cart' button.

Therefore:

```
$('add_to_cart').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("add_to_cart")){
        alert('yes');
        $(this).prop('value', 'Remove from Cart');
        $(this).removeClass("add_to_cart");
        $(this).addClass("remove_from_cart");
    }
    else{
        alert('no');
        $(this).prop('value', 'Add to Cart');
        $(this).addClass("add_to_cart");
        $(this).removeClass("remove_from_cart");
    }
return false; // or preventdefault
}
});
```

Also - id of this element is not valid. Id of element in html can't start with a digit.

---

Edit: Note also that usage of inline 'onclick' attributes are considered bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: `val()` is a function not a property and ID's can be numeric in html5 spec

Comment: I removed this line - I've copied it from the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<input id="069874" class="add_to_cart button" type="button" onclick="addOrRemoveFromCart.call(this)" value="Add To Cart">
```

`$(this).val` alerts the code of the function. You have to call it! Change to `$(this).val()`